# Picking up unchanged defaultValues in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to teach myself react with a simple app (I have a working backend for this too) with movies and categories. What I'm trying to achieve is to allow changing of the entire movie object (well, its just the name and/or year at this point, but really more about the principle). What I would like to achieve is that when I change only the year, the year is picked up from onChange and the name is picked up as the defaultValue that was filled in originally. My backend uses looking up by id, so unless I touch that, that also doesn't send because of me not actually changing it - which makes sense of course. I just can't seem to figure out how to add to the object sent to my backend's app.put the values that weren't changed in the input box. Here's my code for this bit (currently kinda wonky, but really trying to figure out the principle here rather than anything else). Any help greatly appreciated.

Oh and I did look in the documentation, problem is I'm not exactly sure what I'm looking for in the first place, this I managed to figure out using docs and some examples. I'm really rather a beginner so please be gentle :).

```
import React from 'react';
import API from './utils/API';

export default class MoviesModify extends React.Component {
  state = {
    movies: []
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    API.get(`/movies`)
      .then(res => {
        const movies = res.data;
        console.log(movies);
        this.setState({ movies });
      })
  }
  handleChangeId = event => {
    this.setState({ idInp: event.target.value });
  }
  handleChangeName = event => {
    this.setState({ nameInp: event.target.value });
  }
  handleChangeYear = event => {
    this.setState({ yearInp: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmitChange = event => {
    const movie = {
      id: this.state.idInp,
      name: this.state.nameInp,
      year: this.state.yearInp
    };
    console.log(movie);
    API.put(`/movies`, movie)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      }).catch(err => { console.log(err) });
    //window.location.reload();
  }

  handleRemoveId = event => {
    this.setState({ idRem: event.target.value });
  }
  handleRemoveName = event => {
    this.setState({ nameRem: event.target.value });
  }
  handleRemoveYear = event => {
    this.setState({ yearRem: event.target.value });
  }  

  handleSubmitRemove = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const movie = {
      name: this.state.nameInp,
      year: this.state.yearInp
    };
    console.log("this.state");
    console.log(this.state);
    API.delete(`/movies/` + this.state.idRem)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      }).catch(err => { console.log(err) });
    window.location.reload();
  }

render() {
return (
<div className="container">
  <div className="left" style={{'float': 'left', 'width': '40%'}}>
    <div className="leftHeader" style={{'verticalAlign': 'top'}}>
        <h1>Change Movie</h1>
    </div>
    <div className="leftBody" style={{'verticalAlign': 'bottom'}}>
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmitChange}>
      <table border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>movie.id</th>
            <th>movie.name</th>
            <th>movie.year</th>
            <th>Categories</th>
            <th>Change</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        { this.state.movies.map((movie, j)=> <tbody className="tableBody" key={j}>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="id" onChange={this.handleChangeId} defaultValue={movie.id}/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleChangeName} defaultValue={movie.name}/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="year" onChange={this.handleChangeYear} defaultValue={movie.year}/></td>
            <td>{movie.Categories.map((category, i) => category.name + (movie.Categories[i + 1] ? ", " : ""))}</td>
            <td align = "center"><button type="submit">Change</button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>)}
      </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="right" style={{'float': 'right', 'width': '50%'}}>
    <div className="rightHeader" style={{'verticalAlign': 'top'}}>      
        <h1>Remove Movie</h1>
    </div>
    <div className="rightBody" style={{'verticalAlign': 'bottom'}}>
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmitRemove}>
      <table border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>movie.id</th>
            <th>movie.name</th>
            <th>movie.year</th>
            <th>Remove</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody className="tableBody">
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="id" onChange={this.handleRemoveId} /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleRemoveName} /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="year" onChange={this.handleRemoveYear} /></td>
            <td align = "center"><button type="submit">Remove</button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
)
}
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do that, I'm trying something like this, but it's not the correct format

```
<input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleChangeName(movie.id)} defaultValue={movie.name}
```

and then

```
handleChangeName = (event, movieId) => {
    this.setState({ nameInp: event.target.value });
    this.setState({ idRem: movieId });
  }
```

Comment: what I would do: create a function called something like `handeleApiCall` that deals with the API call, and call this function inside `componentDidMount`, `handleSubmitChange` and then, to kind of answer your question, inside all your `handleChange...` functions.

Comment: I think I kind of understand what the idea is here, however I have one more question - say my original movies set has 10 movie objects, then my table will display 10 rows, each row wil lhave a "change" button in the last column, how can I tie this specific button to send id from the same row. Like if I click "change" in row 3 and haven't touched the id, how can I pass in which row the button was pressed ?

Comment: Pass the id as an argument.

Comment: I appended my post with how I'm trying to do that, but it's not how it's supposed to be done, can you point me in the right direction with this ?

Comment: you can get the movieId from your event. Here's an example where I would use the name attribute of an input field: `handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
  };` In this case, I use the name to update the state corresponding to that name.